# Can't move or delete audit messages, but I can edit them in Chat

Tags: bug, chat

Whenever a room owner edits a room's info, a message from the editor's account is posted into the room reflecting the changes. These type of messages are apparently called audit messages, as when you try to delete them you're told you can't delete this audit message.

It is also seemingly impossible to move them to rooms like bin and trash can (at least I couldn't manage it. Clicking the choose button on a room after selecting these messages has no effect).

However, I can seem to edit them to replace their content with something else, as I've done [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8544182#8544182).

It is also not possible to move them after editing them, and if you select multiple messages out of which some are audits and some aren't, only the non audit messages get moved.

Is this by design, or did someone forget to prevent editing them too? It seems only logical that if you can't move them or delete them, you shouldn't be able to edit them.

Comment: Noooo I love this feature/bug.

Comment: I've noticed moderators can delete theirs though.

Comment: I was just about to post this issue today but found this question. +1.